# PyroCMS Using 2.0 Issue with registering new users persists after upgrade

Tags: pyrocms

I get the following error when registering a new user ( not from the admin end)
[image: PyroCMS DB Error]

as a fix , I tried updating to 2.1 but that didnt solve it.. it is worth noting that the registration form shows only 3 fields :

Email, Password and First name ..

I realize it has to do with a setting somewhere but would love any advice to help me save some time.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Either run this query:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `default_profiles` CHANGE `last_name` `last_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  ```
- Or on the control panel go to settings->users and try changing "require last names"

Did you change the available profile fields?

Are you running a clean install of 2.1 or did you upgrade?

Comment: This is an upgrade not a clean install. I tried changing the "require last names" back and forth but to no avail. I compared the DB setup of that table between 2.0 and 2.1 and i dont see any difference. the field lastname should appear conditionally,  I just don't see where that option is in the DB and why it isn't being read properly

Answer (score 0):

Just set the default value for the lastname field in the 'Default_profiles' table. Then it will work fine.